# I keep getting an unwrapping error when passing value to another view controller and set equal to output? (Swift 3.0)

Tags: swift, null, func, unwrap

[image]

I keep getting this error when I am trying to set my function return values to a label output.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class finalData: UIViewController {

var userNum: Int!
var computerNum: Int!

@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.output.text = chooseWinner(userNum: userNum, computerNum: computerNum)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func chooseWinner(userNum : Int, computerNum : Int) -> String {
    if userNum == computerNum {
        return "There is a tie"
    }else if userNum == 1 && computerNum == 2{
        return "You lost!"
    }else if userNum == 1 && computerNum == 3{
        return "You won!"
    }else if userNum == 2 && computerNum == 1{
        return "You won!"
    }
    else if userNum == 2 && computerNum == 3{
        return "You lost!"
    }else if userNum == 3 && computerNum == 1{
        return "You lost!"
    }
    else if userNum == 3 && computerNum == 2{
        return "You won!"
    }else{
        return "value"
    }
}

func findPlayerImage (firstImage: Int) -> UIImage{
    if userNum == 1{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }else if userNum == 2{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }else{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }
}
func findCompImage (secondImage: Int) -> UIImage{
    if computerNum == 1{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }else if computerNum == 2{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }else{
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
    }
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

I am trying to pass the numbers to this view controller and then call the function to return a String (I am making Rock, Paper, Scissors). But, when I set the output = the function, it gives me a unwrapping error.

Comment: Have you connected the `UILabel` to the `IBOutlet` in your storyboard?

Comment: `self.outlet` is probably `nil`.

Comment: Yeah I added it @MattLeFleur

Comment: How do i make output.text != nil? @maddy

Comment: You make sure your `output` outlet is connected to a label in your storyboard.

Comment: @maddy I did do that I wrote '@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!'

Comment: Check the connections inspector on the label in your storyboard and make sure the reference outlet is linked with that outlet in your view controller

Comment: Yeah, it has a reference outlet and it is set to output.

Comment: @FusionPointInc Ah OK, then it will be because `userNum` or `computerNum` (or both) don't have a value

Comment: @MattLeFleur I pass a value to them in another view controller. They have a value when/if I print them.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like viewDidLoad is being called before the value is set. I'll try it out and get back to you :)

Comment: So I presume you're setting the value in `prepareForSegue` in the first view controller. Are you using a custom class for your first view controller? Make sure the view controller in your storyboard is set to that custom class, otherwise `prepareForSegue` won't be called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made sure my connections were good.

Then I passed the value to another storyboard and set the default value of `output` to `"value"`.
When I passed a string into output, it changed.

Thank you everyone above as well. ^